# Resetting Java AudioInputStream loaded from file

Tags: java, audio

A part of my program requires loading of sounds and playing them back when prompted. 
Currently I support loading .wav files that I have "embedded" as resources within my project. To do this I use a line of code like this:

```
sounds[i+1] = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(MyProject.class.getResource("filename.wav"));
```

My next goal is to allow the user to load their own .wav files for playback. To do this I use a line of code like this:

```
sounds[i+1] = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("filename.wav"));
```

Now comes the issue. Naturally I want to be able to play these sounds more than once. In my initial approach I used:

```
sound.markSupported();
sound.mark(Integer.MAX_VALUE); 
/* do stuff with it */
sound.reset();
```

And this worked perfectly fine. However it does not work (crashes upon invocation of reset() ) for audio streams I create from loading files "regularly" (the second method above).

The error I am receiving is

```
java.io.IOException: mark/reset not supported
at java.io.InputStream.reset(InputStream.java:348)
at javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream.reset(AudioInputStream.java:427)....
```

Why is that? 
How should I go about fixing this?

Comment: You have to check whether `sound.markSupported()` return `true` if not you can't use `mark()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you store the Streams in your `sounds[]` array. Just save the info how to create the stream. an OO way to do this would be as follow:

```
public abstract class AudioSource {
    public abstract InputStream getStream() throws IOException;
}

public class FileAudioSource extends AudioSource {

    private final File audioFile;

    public FileAudioSource(File audioFile) {
        this.audioFile = audioFile;
    }

    @Override
    public InputStream getStream() throws FileNotFoundException {
        return new FileInputStream(audioFile);
    }
}

public class ResourceAudioSource extends AudioSource {

    private final String resourceName;

    public ResourceAudioSource(String resourceName) {
        this.resourceName = resourceName;
    }

    @Override
    public InputStream getStream() {
        return this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(resourceName)
    }
}
```

Finally you can create your list:

```
sounds[i+1] = new ResourceAudioSource("resource_filename.wav");
sounds[i+1] = new FileAudioSource(new File("filename.wav"));
```

And if you need the stream just call `sounds[j].getStream()`.

Comment: Thank you, with a couple additional tweaks this works. What I had to do was return a `BufferedInputStream` instead of the pure `FileInputstream` in case of a file resource, otherwise it could not be casted to an `AudioInputStream` and as a result could not be played via clip, which is my current chosen method. Thought I'd write it in case anyone else ever encounters this. 
Out of curiosity, this seems wasteful in terms of complexity, creating and recreating these streams. Are there "cheaper" ways to do it for times when performance is important?